# How can I silence notifications thrown by Harmony Web Protection in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-extensions

For a customer, I had to install the Chrome Plugin Harmony Web Protection. Now when typing in input fields on websites, macOS (system) messages appear in the top right corner that I don't want to see. Can you suppress them? If yes, how?

Comment: How does this relate to Apple products or their use? And if it does, what do you mean with "every field gets annoying messages"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to have nothing to do with Apple software or hardware

Comment: @nohillside: See the second picture. My assumption was that this is a system dialog. If this is not the case, feel free to close this post.

Comment: I don‘t see any pictures in the question? Self-answered questions are fine, but please make sure to write the question so it is understandable without knowing the answer already.

Comment: Right now it‘s not clear whether you get messages directly on the website, via a notification within Chrome, or with the notification service offered by macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it myself, there is an inconspicuous arrow in the top right corner of the message that takes you to the settings. There you can prohibit the display of the messages. Maybe it will help someone.

[image: Settings]
[image: Deactivate]